# How to put a button beside (right) side of another button

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/49/)

As you can see, i got 2 buttons. I want the dislike button to appear next to like button (after text 1). How to do it?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. We need to see your code _in_ the question, not a link to a page. Links rot then break, and when it does your question will not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put buttons and number inside divs and float those divs to left.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/50/

`div {float:left;}`

Comment: i did the same thing here, but why it is not working? http://kchere.16mb.com/

Comment: whole button and span with number have to be wrapped with `<div style="float:left;">` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the button into a container and `display: inline-block` them then. (Important: You should've the same height for the objects when you use this technic.)

```css
#example {
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
}


.like  {background: url(like.png) 5px 50% no-repeat;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 30px;

    float: left;

    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;

    border:#fff 1px solid;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.like:hover {margin-left: 0px;
    background: url(like2.png) 5px 50% no-repeat;
    color: #0c6502;

    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: #0c6502 1px solid;
}

.dislike  { background: url(dislike.png) 5px 50% no-repeat;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 30px;

    float: left;

    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;

    border:#fff 1px solid;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.dislike:hover{background: url(dislike2.png) 5px 50% no-repeat;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: #ff0000 1px solid;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
<div class="button">
    <div>
        <a class="no" id="0" onclick="like(this.id)">
            <div class="like" style="vertical-align:middle" type="image">
                Like
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <span>
        1
    </span>
</div>
<div class="button">
    <div>
        <a class="no" id="0" onclick="dislike(this.id)">
            <div class="dislike" style="vertical-align:middle" type="image">
                Dislike
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <span>
        1
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Then you need to change the position of your indicators, just use `position:absoulte` and reposition them with negative margin values.

Good luck, and ask if there is something not clear enough.